# Looking for a formula to sum cost of all members of a team including each supervisor

Tags: powerquery, sumifs, sumproduct

The easiest way to describe this is to show a sample data set[image: team and org chart]

I have hourly rates for each member of a team, and would like to know the cost of each team at the manager level, including the team leader. So for example, in my diagram, I want the cost of tanya and her team. Top level (Zelda and Greg) can be excluded. I tried doing a sumif formula (see cell B16) but that doesn't work because the range to sum is fewer columns than the range to evaluate, so it's only returning the entries that match in column B. Any suggestions? I thought maybe I could do a powerquery and merge the supervisor = manager, but I need a model to help me think it through.

Answer (score 1):

Try B16

```
= sumif($b$2:$b$15,a16,$a$2:$a$15) + sumif($c$2:$c$15,a16,$a$2:$a$15) + sumif($d$2:$d$15,a16,$a$2:$a$15) + sumif($e$2:$e$15,a16,$a$2:$a$15)
```

and copy that down

Comment: Thank you! Thoughtful of you to write it out for me.

Comment: Please accept the answer as solved if this answered the question   Thanks